# How do I dig into an applications source code?

Tags: macos, filesystems, source-code

I'm trying to look into different applications on my Macbook and see their source code in order to better understand how certain applications are built and what languages/frameworks they use. Perhaps part of my confusion comes from not having enough of an in depth understanding of application infrastructure.

However, I have taken multiple apps on my computer, cd'd into their contents and looked through every directory I can yet I cant seem to find any actual source code. All I find is CodeSigniture files, CodeResource files, and some code like .plist files. How do i find the .js/.py/.c/.cpp files?

I'm wondering if they somehow encrypt these files for maintaining security/intellectual property. But if that's the case, what is my computer reading in order to execute these applications?

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Programs may be interpreted (the source code is parsed and converted to system-level instructions "on the fly" each time the instruction is needed) or compiled (the source code is parsed and converted to system-level instructions ONCE, and the system-level instructions stored for later use and reuse). If an application is written in a language that is normally compiled - C, C++, C#, Pascal, etc. - you will not get to see the source code; it doesn't need to be installed on your computer for the program to run, only the system-level instructions (this is what's called an EXE file in Windows).

Other languages, like ECMAscript, PowerShell, Perl, Python, Ruby, etc., are interpreted, and for those, you can usually find the source code by looking at the installed files.

Be aware that some implementations of some interpreted languages also allow for "wrappers" where the source code is converted into an 'encoded' form (e.g., Base64) and appended to a customized interpreter, so that it *looks* to the user like a compiled program (i.e., an EXE on Windows). If your application was made with one of these, you won't be able to find the source easily.

Comment: It's accurate, but it's a bit Windows-oriented. Also, very few users are using ECMAscript, PowerShell, Perl, Python, Ruby, etc. on a Mac. Most just grab an 'app' from the App Store… & run it. Anything that comes to them via that route is going to fall firmly into your first paragraph.

Comment: That app from the App Store may well be Electron-based, meaning the Javascript code is still around, though typically packed.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I'm a non-UNIX/Linux (which includes non-Mac) guy, so I'll tend to use _examples_ from the Windows world (unless one of my other OS experiences [e.g., mainframe, CTOS/BTOS] is more relevant), hence my comments about "EXE" files. My _understanding_ of the UNIX/Linux world is that scripting languages of whatever ilk are fairly common and popular, so I assumed that that was more-or-less also true of the Mac.

Comment: @DanielB - That sounds like Electron would more-or-less fall under my third paragraph.

Comment: If an app is, for instance, Java-based, then it will have a Java/app/ folder inside the app contents, containing an actual .exe, .jar & associated bits & pieces, & the contents of the macOS folder will just be a stub to launch it. Most 'consumer' apps, however just don't work that way.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no source code inside an app.**

They are **[compiled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler)** from source code into an actual executable file - if you look inside TheApplication.app/Contents/MacOS/TheApplication - that it the compiled app itself. Pretty much everything else you see in there is either a library that the app is dependant on, or a simple plaintext xml file to govern such things as language changes etc.

Also note that if you mess with an app from a recognised developer, from the App Store etc, you might flag it as no longer matching its code-signature & you will need to trash it & re-download the original again. macOS is getting more & more strict on apps being tampered with.
Catalina is going to be even more strict on this & require not only code signing, but also [Notarizing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_your_app_before_distribution), making app modification by 3rd parties almost impossible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reverse-engineer a binary/executable file, then you do have the option of using [Ghidra](https://ghidra-sre.org/). There are some tutorials from independent developers on YouTube to also help you get started ([I found this one approachable](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fTGTnrgjuGA)).

As mentioned in the other answers, compiled languages (e.g., `*.cpp`, `*.c`, `*.java`) won't have the files neatly available, so you'll be doing some digging.